# Namespaced Rails Routes incorrect Named Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I recently tried namespacing a resource route like so

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :organization
  root 'organization#index'
 end
```

However now when I try to go to the resource like this

```
<%= link_to 'Show', @organization %>
```

I get an error `undefined method organization_url`

I know I can work around it by using...

```
<%= link_to 'Show', admin_organization_path(@organization) %>
```

Is there any way to rewrite the route so `@organization` can properly create the Helper Path?

Comment: Not too sure, but try `<%= link_to 'Show', [:admin, @organization_assignment] %>`. I know it works with `form_for`; it might work for this.

Comment: Also, is the variable`@organization_assignment` or `@organization`? It seems to be mixed in your code above.

Comment: Oop  yes it is @organizaton. I removed some things to make it easier to read on here. Thanks for the advice I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Great! Just posted a formal answer answering in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just like with [`form_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for), you are able to use namespaces as symbols in an array with [`link_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to), like so:

```
[:admin, @organization]
```

And thus your `link_to` would look like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', [:admin, @organization_assignment] %>
```

This also serves in the case you have a nested route. You would use an array like so:

```
[@organization, @organization_assignment]
```

Used with the `link_to` it would be equal to using `organization_organization_assignment_path(@organization, @organization_assignment)`